# Authentication method for REST Web Service using SecurityContext

Tags: java, web-services, rest, authentication, jax-rs

A Java EE web app was developed which has a REST Web service using Jersey.

Could anyone point out an example or a path to code in Java an authentication to user access using the SecurityContext class in java (JAX-RS)

Please suggest any other method you can think of.

Answer (score 1):

This is good tiutorial about [SecurityContext](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24983/secure.htm#RESTF255) try this

Comment: I've worked on this tutorial earlier. My problem is that how we can assign the roles for users. <if (securityContext.isUserInRole("admin"))  return "Hello World!";> this is the server side code for authentication, but how we can set these roles on successful login at the client side?

Comment: @NelsonPaul, apparently the way to set up users and roles programmatically is container-dependent. For example, with embedded Jetty you must set up a `Constraint`, then set up a `ConstraintMapping`, and install that constraint mapping into a `ConstraintSecurityHandler` adding a custom `LoginService`. Whew! The custom `LoginService` is the key; you can do all the authentication inside the implementation of this interface. See Jetty's own `MappedLoginService` for an idea of what the methods mean and for some of the default implementations you can leverage.

Comment: you may include role in access token if you using OAuth2